# Deleting non-empty folders and specific file types

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, macos-carbon

1. What is the best way to remove a folder, deleting all subfolders and files?
2. What is the best way to remove files with a specific extension; e.g., if I want to remove only files with '.txt' extension?

Cocoa or carbon.

Answer (score 3):

To remove a directory tree (or file), use [`-[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/removeItemAtPath:error:). This deletes the files directly (and it will delete **all of them**); if you want to move the item to the Trash instead, use [`NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation) .

As for removing only files with specific extensions: Get each pathname's `pathExtension` and use `caseInsensitiveCompare:` to compare it to the ones you're looking for, then remove the file if it's on your hit list.

If you want to combine the two (i.e., remove only files within a directory tree that have a given extension), you'll need to get a directory enumerator from the NSFileManager and walk the directory tree yourself, removing files one by one.

Comment: Unless its an internal application file it would probably be better to use the recycle operation (:

Answer (score 1):

Yep, be sure to use therecycle bin unless of course they are files the user shouldn't see/know about.

Comment: What's a "recycle bin"? Question is about Cocoa so you need to start thinking "Trash"!!

Answer (score 1):

To remove files with specific extension..

One way at least..  This example is just looking in the application documents directory for any files with the extension jpg and removing them..

```
    NSFileManager *fManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dir = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *files = [fManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dir error:&error];

    for (NSString *file in files) {

          if ([[[file pathExtension] lowercaseString] isEqualToString: @"jpg"]) 
          {
              [fManager removeItemAtPath: [dirstringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&error];
              NSLog(@"removed: %@",file);
          }

          if (error) {
             //deal with it
          }
     }
```